# Why does it return NA value when I create a new variable using mutate() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I compute the following code:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(PPE = (prop)+(equip))
# create new variable depending on this
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(dependent = (PPE - lag(PPE))/lag(assets))
```

and when  I look at the data, PPE returns NA because equip has a NA value. However, say prop = 1 and equip = NA, I would like PPE to return 1 (and not NA).
How can I change this? There is an example below of what I would want (where the first observation has to return NA for the dependent variable as I am using lag):

```
prop    equip    assets   PPE   dependent
  1       NA        2      1        NA 
​  1       NA        1      1        0.5
​  NA       4        2      4        3 
​  3       3         1      6        1 
​  8       NA        2      8        2
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `lag` by default fills with `default = NA` as the first element..  If we need to get 1, then we can `replace` the `NA` with `1 or specify the` default` with a different value

```
df %>% 
     mutate(dependent = replace_na((PPE - lag(PPE))/lag(assets), 1))
```

---

If the error is from `prop + equip`, it is because one of the column have `NA` values and adding an element or multiplying or other arithmetic operations on `NA` returns `NA`.  To avoid that, we can use `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
 df$PPE <- rowSums(df[c("prop", "equip")], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: ok, and for the first line of code, I don't use lag and still get that problem, so what would I do there? Thanks!!

Comment: @coding_sailor sorry, i thought it is from the second code block.  I updated the post.  The first NA is because of `+`.  You can use `rowSums` as in the update

Comment: great thanks, and if it would have been for example prop+equip-assets in an equation, I assume I wouldn't be able to use rowSums but would need to use another function?

Comment: @coding_sailor Yes, you can do that by `rowSums(cbind(df[c("prop", "equip")],-df$assets), na.rm = TRUE)`